# IVR in TwiML; how do I set keypresses to dial particular numbers?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm trying to code an IVR in TwiML on the Twilio site. Ideally, what I would like to happen is:

- Pressing "1" dials a number that I set.
- Pressing "2" dials a number that I set.
- Pressing "3" brings me to a directory. Nested within number "3", they are presented again with several choices, each of which dials a particular number.

I think I'm supposed to use `action` somewhere, but I am not sure how to set "if" conditions for dialing. My knowledge on coding is extremely rudimentary at best, but here is what I have set up so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Pause length="2"/>
  <Say voice="alice" language="en-gb">Thank you for calling our company, your number one source for commercial real estate listings.</Say>
  <Gather numDigits="1">
    <Say voice="alice" language="en-gb">Press 1 for Sales to Sign Up and Stand Out!</Say>
    <Say voice="alice" language="en-gb">Press 2 for Support!</Say>
    <Say voice="alice" language="en-gb">Press 3 for our company directory!</Say>
  </Gather>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right - you have to use action on  . This action URL will get "DIGITS" that user pressed and then you can take appropriate action.

See a sample below (**action="/abcxyzDemoIvr"**).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Pause length="2"/>
  <Say voice="alice" language="en-gb">Thank you for calling our company, your number one source for commercial real estate listings.</Say>
  <Gather numDigits="1" action="<urlHere>/abcxyzDemoIvr">
    <Say voice="alice" language="en-gb">Press 1 for Sales to Sign Up and Stand Out!</Say>
    <Say voice="alice" language="en-gb">Press 2 for Support!</Say>
    <Say voice="alice" language="en-gb">Press 3 for our company directory!</Say>
  </Gather>
</Response>
```

Sample of how you can organise your action URL for [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) is also mentioned below :

```
app.post('/abcxyzDemoIvr',
         function(i_Req,o_Res)
           {
               var ivrTwilRes = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
               var iGathered=i_Req.body.Digits ;

               if ( iGathered == 1)
                  {
                      ivrTwilRes.say("Action for Sales to Sign Up and Stand Out!");
                      ivrTwilRes.redirect( { method : 'GET' } , "/abcxyzDemoIvr_salesSignupAndStandOut" );
                      /*do your stuff here */
                  }
               else if (  iGathered == 2 )
                  {

                      ivrTwilRes.say("Action for Support");
                      ivrTwilRes.redirect( { method : 'GET' } , "/abcxyzDemoIvr_support" );
                      /*do your stuff here */
                  }   
                else if (  iGathered == 3 )
                     {

                         ivrTwilRes.say("Action for CompanyDirectory");
                         ivrTwilRes.redirect( { method : 'GET' } , "/abcxyzDemoIvr_companyDirectory" );
                         /*do your stuff here */
                     }                   
               else if (  iGathered == '*' )
                  {
                      ivrTwilRes.redirect( { method : 'GET' } , "/abcxyzDemoIvrMenu" );

                  }                                    
              else
                 {
                      ivrTwilRes.say("I'm sorry, that is not a valid choice. Please make a choice from the menu").redirect( { method : "GET" } );
                 }
               ivrTwilRes.say("Thank you for calling my IVR . Goodbye.",
                               {
                                  language:'en-gb',
                                  voice : 'woman'
                               }
                              )
                          .pause({ length : 3 } )
                          .hangup();

               o_Res.set('Content-Type','text/xml');
               o_Res.send(ivrTwilRes.toString());

               console.log("========================== Response Starts Here (for abcxyzDemoIvr post)============================");
               console.log(o_Res);
               console.log("========================== Response Ends Here (for abcxyzDemoIvr post)============================");


           }
       );


app.post('/abcxyzDemoIvr_CallAgent',
         function(i_Req,o_Res)
           {
               var ivrTwilRes = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
               var agentNum=i_Req.body.Digits ;
               /*
               console.log("========================== Request Starts Here (for abcxyzDemoIvr_CallAgent post)============================");
               console.log(i_Req.body);
               console.log("========================== Request Ends Here (for abcxyzDemoIvr_CallAgent post)============================");
               */

              var whichAgent = /*your logic to get which number to dial */

               ivrTwilRes.say("Connecting you to agent " + whichAgent )
                                  .dial({callerId:'+447777777777',action:"/abcxyzDemoIvr_postCallHandler",method:"GET"},
                                         function()
                                             {
                                                  this.number('+44xxxxxxxxxx',{url:"/abcxyzDemoIvr_screenCaller",method:"GET"});
                                             }
                                        );

               o_Res.set('Content-Type','text/xml');
               o_Res.send(ivrTwilRes.toString());


           }
       );
```